# Capacitor connected across two isolated sources

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, classical-electrodynamics

Lets say there are two isolated sources of positive charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ $(q_1>q_2)$ located sufficiently far apart. If the two are connected to the two plates of a capacitor, then what is the resulting charge distribution across each capacitor plate?